# About Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have created small application for which I have used bootstrap and HTML for front end and for backend PHP( Codeigniter framework) is used. My question is that how to call codeigniter's controller from bootstrap modal(i.e. popup menu based).
Thanks.

Comment: Just link what ever you need to right URL which will trigger right controller. If that is the question. Since nobody knows what do you ask exactly, [read this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask correctly and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to codeigniter please have a look to link .
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html
This might help you

Comment: thanks but i am using codeigniter from last two days.

Answer (score 0):

You can can create a helper function where you can call your controller. Then you can call that helper function in modal. You can also use jquery and ajax.